# Which tools are use in graphics design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, designers, corel-draw

For graphics design, I am using Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop, Corel draw, Indesign, and also Adobe XD.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Paper is a pretty common tool among graphic designers, as are pencils, erasers, pens, markers and a notebook. Some people are known for using rulers, maybe a compass or a french curve. Exacto knife, brushes, scissors, paint or watercolor seem to be optional. For package design a bit of different stock of cardboard could be useful. For print design a color book is used by some. Some reference in the bookshelf, a desk and chair.

A phone especially a smarphone seems common enough, maybe a tablet. A laptop seems to be standard issue but some prefer a workstation. One big and/or a few medium sized screens seem to be useful. A mouse is fairly common, a digitizer a bit less, a keyboard almost a must. A camera, scanner, screen calibrator and spectrometer nice to have. External harddrive and an archivial and backup strategy helps. A server or a cloud instance useful, email a must. A car can be useful for meeting clients and for negitiating with printshops, binders etc.

Software wise, an operating system, a text editor and a few browsers. A virtual machine for testing webpages for people inclined to test their pages, a vector drawing software needed, a publication layout software recommended, a raster editor, 3D application optional, a video editor and animation suite optional, a ux design application for so inclined, cad application optional. More than that you should be compatible with others so be sure you can make and decompose PDF files and SVG's, open and edit multi channel bitmap formats.

Thats about it.

Comment: You could also color papers, scissors, paint, a napkin, a building to project something, led lights on the facade of a building, laser lights on a stadium...

Comment: Scissors and paint were mentioned @Rafael not sure about a stadium but i suppose it might come handy. Not a common tool herabout but i dont know maybe it is important to somebody ;)